# Trying to find a way to better indent automatically with emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

I find my self manually correcting indentation too often, so I am looking for a way to automatically indent a line according to mode when I enter or leave a line.  At the moment I am just wrapping the `next-line` and `previous-line` commands with `indent-according-to-mode` and rebinding my C-n and C-p to the new functions like so:

```
(defun next-line-and-indent (&optional arg try-vscroll)
  "Move to the next line and indent according to mode."
  (interactive)
  (indent-according-to-mode)
  (next-line arg try-vscroll)
  (indent-according-to-mode))

(defun previous-line-and-indent (&optional arg try-vscroll)
  "Move to the previous line and indent according to mode."
  (interactive)
  (indent-according-to-mode)
  (previous-line arg try-vscroll)
  (indent-according-to-mode))
```

This works, but is dirty feeling and whatnot, also it would not cover a line being entered or exitted by any means other than C-n and C-p.  Is there some hook I can't find like `enter-line` and `leave-line`?

Comment: What's wrong with the indenting performed usually? You can always select the complete text and do `indent-region`.

Comment: i am lazy and there are more automatic ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use pre- and post-command-hook to ascertain whether point is on the same line after the command as it was before it?

```
(defun my-auto-indent-remember ()
  "Remember the current beginning and end of line."
  (setq my-auto-indent-line-beginning-position (line-beginning-position))
  (setq my-auto-indent-line-end-position (line-end-position)))

(defun my-auto-indent ()
  "Indent if we have changed lines."
  (and (boundp 'my-auto-indent-line-beginning-position)
       (boundp 'my-auto-indent-line-end-position)
       (or (< (point) my-auto-indent-line-beginning-position)
           (> (point) my-auto-indent-line-end-position))
       (indent-according-to-mode)))

(add-hook 'pre-command-hook 'my-auto-indent-remember)
(add-hook 'post-command-hook 'my-auto-indent)
```

I simply can't imagine this being a good idea, btw, but I had to try it out :)

With it enabled, I've *already* experienced undesired re-indentation just attempting to copy that code after indenting it four spaces for Stack Overflow.

Whenever the indentation is wrong, I find that a quick `indent-region` will almost always fix everything.

This code doesn't handle the "leaving a line" bit, btw, and I'm not sure how that would work post-command to be honest. You might have to catch known movement commands pre-command, and indent there. You *could* easily test the idea with an unconditional (indent-according-to-mode) in my-auto-indent-remember, though.

Comment: i am actually quite liking what I posted in my question with a few major-mode exceptions, and am using a mode hook to tone it down for those specific modes.  In the case of indenting for stuff that shouldn't be indented in a mode (for example 4 spaces in for the SO markdown stuff, i have just been C-u 4 indent-rigidly.

Comment: I see what you me regarding the leaving the line being hard to catch, being that it can be done so many different ways.

Comment: i suppose i could just: 

(defun my-auto-indent ()
  "indent all the damned time."
  (indent-according-to-mode))
(add-hook 'pre-command-hook 'my-auto-indent)
(add-hook 'post-command-hook 'my-auto-indent)

but will probably result in slowness and insanity.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
(define-key global-map (kbd "RET") 'newline-and-indent)
```

That should switch to the new line and automatically indent it according to the current indentation settings.

Comment: i already do something like this, using: reindent-then-newline-and-indent however that is not exactly what i am looking for.